# Magento 2 Layout handle forward / redirection works?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layout, magento2.3.4

I just want to know is there any concept of Layout handle auto forward / redirection concept available ?
Let me Explain in detail.

1. Step-1: I have a controller folder called "Test" and action file name "Index"
2. Step-2: I have another controller folder called "Index" and action file name "Index"
3. Step-3: Actually I should create 2 layout handles to display the pages

   1. routeid_test_index.xml
   2. routeid_index_index.xml

      But I did create only one layout handle called "**routeid_index_index.xml**"
      And one of my form action I have given action name as "**frontname/test/index**" but I am seeing the "**frontname/index/index**" action execution and it is loading "**routeid_index_index.xml**" file block class and template content.

Is there any possibility to happen like this in magento 2 ?
[I am using magento 2.3.4 version]

Comment: Is the "frontname/test/index" page? or just action?
If it's a page, then you need to create the XML file.

Comment: no it's just an action. in this case will it auto redirect to "routeid_index_index.xml" or "frontname_index_index" action..?

Comment: I understood what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to create ajax call and receive the values from it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){ 
       var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl() . 'frontname/test/index' ?>";

       $('#your_forid').submit(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var formData = JSON.stringify( $('#your_formid').serializeArray() );
           $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: formData,
              success: function(response) {
                //excutes your code here
              }
        });
     });
</script>
```